# extract a letter from a string in Lua

Tags: lua

i have the string price that has a value with a number in it. I have code that extracts the number, I need help to figure out how to have another string (pricechar) with only the "k" in it

```
price="1k"

--pricechar=...

pricenum=string.match(price,"%d+")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all non-numeric characters, similar to how you do it for numbers:

```
pricechar = string.match(price,"[^%d]+")
```

Comment: Why not `%D+` ?

Answer (score 0):

To get both values at the same time:

```
pricenum, pricechar = string.match(price,"(%d+)(.*)")
```